# Subject–auxiliary inversions beginning with an adverb

Tags: grammar, adverbs, auxiliary-verbs, subject-verb-inversion, adverb-position

I am interested in subject–auxiliary inversions when the sentence begins with an adverb or an adverbial phrase. If the adverb is not *negative* (for instance, "not only" or "never"), can we invert the usual word order of subject + verb?

For example, can we turn "It faded slowly" into "Slowly did it fade"?

Comment: The acceptability (it's meaningless trying to define 'grammaticality' here) of this style varies immensely with register. In a work of fiction by Tolkien, 150%. In the local pub, expect to be barred or thumped. In a scientific account, expect the editor to send it back. // 'Slowly[,] it faded' is far more generally idiomatic. / Note that idiomaticity varies even with negative adverbs. 'Never did I say that' has a similar distribution to 'Slowly did it fade'.

Comment: Yes: the fronting of an adverb does not prevent subject-auxiliary inversion occurring in this kind of interrogative. But are you sure you meant the second sentence to be an interrogative? (You've added a question mark).

Comment: @BillJ The question mark belongs to the question Can we turn ... into ...?, not to the "Slowly did it fade" part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verily say I unto thee that the way I have begun this sentence is antiquated and idiosyncratic.

You could use it but you'd sound like Henry V.

Even if you modernised the language by saying *Honestly am I telling you* you'd still sound odd, a bit more like Yoda this time.